# Prove $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{2024}a_i<314$ where $a_1=2$, $a_i=2\sin\frac{a_{i-1}}2$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality, contest-math, recursion

> Let $a_1=2$ and $a_i=2\sin\frac{a_{i-1}}2$ for $i\ge2$. Prove that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{2024}a_i<314$.

In fact, $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{2024}a_i\approx298.796$, so the inequality is very strong.

I tried to establish inequalities with Taylor's series, and got $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{2024}a_i<582$. This is not enough. We need better (more accurate) ways to estimate the series.

This question is from the "$\pi$ day math contest" of THU, which has ended.

Comment: If you can prove the inequality $2\sin(\tfrac{\sqrt{\tfrac{12}{k}}}{2}) \le \sqrt{\tfrac{12}{k+1}}$, then, by induction $a_k \le \sqrt{\tfrac{12}{k}}$, from which it follows $\sum_{k = 1}^{2024}a_k \le \sum_{k = 1}^{2024}\sqrt{\tfrac{12}{k}} \le \sqrt{12}(2\sqrt{2024}-1) \approx 308.23$.

Comment: What JimmyK4542 said! Writing $a_n=2b_n$ we have the recurrence $b_n=\sin(b_{n-1})$. Which reminds veterans of the site of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3215/11619). Potentially this is a duplicate, but the focus there is different, so we need to check a few things (and I want to solicit more opinions before acting anyway).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Two of the answers to that question prove the asymptotic behavior of the sequence, without explicit bounds. In the third answer it is shown that $\frac{3}{x^2} + 1 + \cdots<\frac{3}{\sin^2 x}$ and that is exactly the inequality from JimmyK4542's comment, unless I am mistaken. But the proof is not very rigorous, claiming that some “... remaining coefficients are positive.” – I would not close it as a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks @MartinR. So I will refrain from voting to close as a dupe for now. A fond hope is that some of the other threads linked to that target may have the missing pieces (happens occasionally). Material to dig through to anyone so inclined :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following is strongly inspired by JimmyK4542's comment and [Convergence of $\sqrt{n}x_{n}$ where $x_{n+1} = \sin(x_{n})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3215/42969).

Set $b_n = a_n/2$, then $b_1 = 1$ and $b_{n+1} = \sin(b_n)$. In [Convergence of $\sqrt{n}x_{n}$ where $x_{n+1} = \sin(x_{n})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3215/42969) it is shown that
$$
 b_n \sim \sqrt{\frac{3}{n}} \text{ for } n \to \infty \, .
$$
This suggests that an explicit extimate of the form
$$ \tag{1}
 b_n \le \sqrt{\frac{3}{n+2}}
$$
might hold for all $n \ge 1$. If that is true then
$$
\begin{align}
 \sum_{n=1}^{2024} a_n &\le 2  \sum_{n=1}^{2024} \sqrt{\frac{3}{n+2}}
= 2 \sqrt 3 \sum_{n=3}^{2026} \frac{1}{\sqrt n} \\
&< 2 \sqrt 3 \int_2^{2026} \frac{dx}{\sqrt x}
= 4 \sqrt 3 (\sqrt{2026} - \sqrt 2) \\
&\approx 302.048 < 314 \, .
\end{align}
$$

In order to prove $(1)$ by induction we need to show that
$$
\sin \sqrt{\frac 3k} \le \sqrt{\frac{3}{k+1}} \text{ for } k \ge 3 \, .
$$
With the substitution $x = \sqrt{3/k}$ this is equivalent to
$$ \tag{2}
 \sin^2(x) \le \frac{3x^3}{3 + x^2} \text{ for } 0 < x \le 1
$$
or
$$ \tag{3}
\frac{1}{\sin^2(x)} > \frac{1}{x^2} + \frac 13 \text{ for } 0 < x \le 1 \, .
$$

I will now prove inequality $(3)$, but I wonder if there is a simpler way.

For $0 < x < \pi$ is (see e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Power_series_expansion))
$$
 \frac{1}{\sin(x)} = \csc(x)
 =\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }{\frac {(-1)^{n+1}2\left(2^{2n-1}-1\right)B_{2n}}{(2n)!}}x^{2n-1} \\
 = \frac 1x + \frac{1}{6} x +\frac{7}{360}x^{3}+\frac{31}{15120}x^{5}+\cdots
$$
where $B_n$ are the [Bernoulli numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number). $B_{2n}$ is negative if $n$ is even, and positive otherwise, so that $(-1)^{n+1}B_{2n}$ is positive, i.e. all non-zero coefficients in that series are positive.

It follows that for $0 < x < \pi$
$$
 \frac{1}{\sin^2(x)} > \left(\frac 1x + \frac x6\right)^2
> \frac{1}{x^2} + \frac 13
$$
and that completes the proof.

Comment: I don't understand how the form $\sqrt{\frac3{n+2}}$ was obtained, or at least predicted?

Comment: @youthdoo: I looked for an upper bound which is asymptotically $\sqrt{3/n}$ for large $n$. We have $b_1 = 1$, therefore I “guessed” that $b_n \le \sqrt{3/(n+2)}$ might do the job. Then I proved that this is indeed true.

Comment: I see. This is difficult for a contest where people couldn't "look for large $n$".

Comment: Consider the function $$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sin^2(x)}-\frac{1}{x^2},\quad x\in(0,\pi),$$
we can get
$$f'(x)=2\frac{\sin^3x-x^3\cos x}{x^3\sin^3x}>0,\forall x\in(0,\pi),$$
by $$\left(\frac{\sin x}{x} \right)^3 > \cos x,\forall x\in(0,\pi).$$
So $f(x)>f(0)=\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=\frac13$, for $x\in(0,\pi)$.

Comment: @Riemann: Yes, that is a bit simpler. The last inequality is proven here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2088715/42969. – I am still looking for the “nicest” proof that $\frac{1}{\sin^2(x)} > \frac{1}{x^2} + \frac 13$, perhaps I will post that as a separate question some time ...

Comment: @ 
Martin R That will be nice.